# How does cin object converts characters to different types as user needes?

Tags: c++, cin, istream

How does `std::cin` object deal with different types while it is an instance of `basic_istream<char>` (`istream`)?

Comment: Do you understand how `cout` can accept different types, like `int` and `std::string`. What then if you have `struct S {};` will `cin` or `cout` accept either of those?

Comment: No, `cin` and `cout` would not accept `S` unless I defineded an operator to deal with `S` but `cin` and `cout`deal with `int` and `std::string` well.

Comment: Look at [gcc's istream source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00912_source.html).

Comment: I don't understand how `istream` accepts all of the fundamental types while it is a `char` instance of the template `basic_istream<T>` @NickyC

Comment: That's basic C++: [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

Comment: @AsmM What do you mean by "accepts"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>` models an input stream of characters of type `CharT`. It provides both relatively low-level and relatively high-level access to that input stream. You can, for example, call `std::cin.get()` in order to retrieve the next character from the input stream; this will always return `CharT`, since that's the underlying type of characters in the stream. However, `basic_istream` also provides the *formatted input functions*, whose purpose is to interpret that character stream as an encoding of some type, which could potentially be `int`, `std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>`, or something else. Thus, while the stream does not consist of `int`s, there is an `operator>>` that extracts an `int` value by reading digits successively from a `char` stream and interpreting them as the base-10 representation of an integer. The `operator>>` function is overloaded so that it can be used to extract various different types.